# How to search data in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchbar

I have data in local file, I have loaded them into the tableView, and now I want to search/filter via search bar.

I have tried some solutions I've found on the Internet, but I don't know how to access specific data in my structure.

Here is part of the structure:

```
struct Model: Codable {
    var data: [Description]
}

struct Description: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var city: String
    var description: String
    var countryId: Int
    var webSite: String
    var status: Int
    var accountType: Int
    var addDate: String
    var placeGroupId: Int
    var longitude: Double
    var latitude: Double
    var distance: Double
    var working: Bool
    var promotion: String
    var repertoire: Repertoire
    var workingHour: WorkingHour
    var country: Country
    var reviewNum: Int
    var score: Double
    var placeImgUrl: String
}

var model: Model?
```

and here is some code from my ViewController:

```
var filteredObjects = [Description]()

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    <#code#>
    }
}
```

I have variable model, which is type of struct Model. Structure Model have a variable data which is type of struct Description. And finally, in structure Description I have variable name. My tableView cells shows names of models (model?.data[indexPathrow.row].name). Now, I need to search by names shown in tableView cells. I hope I explained it clearly. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `objects` is also `[Description]` and represents the data source array

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController : UISearchController)
{
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
    if searchString.isEmpty {
        filteredObjects.removeAll()
    } else {
        filteredObjects = objects.filter{ $0.name.range(of: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil } 
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In the table view data source methods display `objects` or `filteredObjects` depending on `searchController.isActive`

Comment: Sorry, I have to search model by name. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: `Model` doesn't have a property `name`

Comment: Ok. I have variable model, which is type of struct Model. Structure Model have a variable data which is type of struct Description. And finally, in structure Description I have variable name.
My tableView cells shows names of models (model?.data[indexPathrow.row].name). Now, I need to search by names shown in tableView cells. I hope I explained it more clearly now.
Thank You very much!

Comment: Declare the data source array as non-optional array `[Description]` and assign `model.data` to it. Actually `model` is irrelevant for searching and displaying the data.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thank You once again.

Comment: I did it. Thanks once again!